# Sort array by highest value calculated from contents

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have an array of strings like this:

> ["Brazil (62)", "PalestinianTerritoryOccupied (6)", "Macedonia (2)",
>   "Germany (6)"]

I want to sort them by the highest value but it's got me stumped. I've tried all sorts of weird, wonderful (and useless) things like:

```
cont.sort! { |it| it.scan(/\d+/).to_s.to_i}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sort_by {|e| e[/\d+/].to_i }.reverse
```

should do the trick. You can write this one in a more efficient and elegant way (see comments), like in the following:

```
sort_by {|e| -e[/\d+/].to_i }
```

Note the `-`.

Using sort you can do:

```
sort {|a, b| b[/\d+/].to_i <=> a[/\d+/].to_i }
```

*EDIT*

[String#[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) has been suggested in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately 2 and 26 get placed next to each other - same as 1 and 11 etc. Getting closer though!

Comment: Yeah, just needs converting to an integer with `.to_i` after `[0]` in each case.

Comment: Easier than `s.match(/(\d+)/)[0]` is simply `s[/\d+/]`. Behold the power of [`String#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Comment: Also, a tip: when you want a descending sort of numeric values use `sort_by{ … -n }` instead of `sort_by{ … n }.reverse` to speed things up (and type less).

Comment: Yes definitely better. I'll update the answer. I don't know why but I tend to forget about String#[]. Probably it's not that an intuitive method.

Comment: @Phrogz The tip is great! I want to update the answer with this one too but I don't what to take all the credit for that. How shall I proceed?

Comment: @lucapette Feel free to put it in your answer. It's far better for SO that the accepted answer has the best possible code in it than to try and give credit to the right person.

Comment: @Phrogz I've done it because it's a really good tip and I like the idea that other people will learn it.